# React and this.props.results.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

after tried to set a simple search in the logs show this:

[image: error]

everything seems very ok and standardized so a couple of searches i still have any idea why this error is happening.

i've tried with fetch and the same result

please, someone can elucidate, why this error is happening?

the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Suggestions from "./suggestions";

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      term: "",
      error: false,
      results: []
    };
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState(
      { term: e.target.value },

      () => {
        axios
          .get("/search?q=" + this.state.term)
          .then(res => this.setState({ results: res.data }))
          .catch(() => this.setState({ error: true }));
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="searchbox">
        <div>
          <form>
            <input
              ref={input => {
                this.search = input;
              }}
              value={this.state.term}
              onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search..."
            />

            <button type="submit">
              <i className="search icon" />
            </button>
            <Suggestions results={this.state.results} />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

the suggestion

```
import React from "react";

const Suggestions = props => {
    const resultList = props.results.map(r => <li key={r.id}>{r.title}</li>);
    return <ul>{resultList}</ul>;
};

export default Suggestions;
```

response

[image: response]

Comment: What does your response data look like? Maybe the response is an object, and you need to access the array with e.g. `res.data.result`. Maybe the response is also empty if there are no results for the search.

Comment: @Tholle is a array of posts, i gonna edit and post the response screen. i changed results to posts and the same

Comment: change .then(res => this.setState({ results: res.data })) to res.data.posts

Comment: @SakoBu thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.data` will give you the entire parsed JSON response, but you want the array that is the value of the `posts` property instead.

```
axios
  .get("/search?q=" + this.state.term)
  .then(res => this.setState({ results: res.data.posts }))
  .catch(() => this.setState({ error: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you need use

```
axios
          .get("/search?q=" + this.state.term)
          .then(res => this.setState({ results: res.data.posts }))
          .catch(() => this.setState({ error: true }));
```

and not

```
axios
          .get("/search?q=" + this.state.term)
          .then(res => this.setState({ results: res.data }))
          .catch(() => this.setState({ error: true }));
```